# Take photos in iOS without preview screen

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to use a UIImagePickerController to take photos without each photo going to the  Preview screen?

I need for my users to be able to take multiple photos and right now they must hit a button to  open the camera, hit the shutter button, and then hit the Use button on the Preview screen.  Is there any way cut off this last step and skip the Preview screen altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [tutorial using AVFoundation](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/) with which you can take photos using a live camera preview *styled and sized as you wish* and without the annoying confirmation wiew.